# JavaScript Button/Input/Function, string reversal

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, input

I need to make a function that accepts a user input in the form of a string, then when a button is hit returns it reversed. so far I have the function to reverse it, the button and user input field. However i'm struggling to get it to pass the information back and forth.

```
Html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>String reverser</title>
 <!-- imports script containing function-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="problem23.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<!--defines user input field-->
    <input title="userinput" type="text" id="inputValueId" name="inputId"/> 

<!--defines button which calls on the reverse function in javascript file-->

    <button name="reverseButton" type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="reverse()">Click me!</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>

function reserve(conversionHolder){
    //picks up value
    var userInput= document.getelementById("inputValueId").value;
    //converts value
    var conversionHolder= userInput.split('').reverse().join('');
    //passes value outside of function?
    return conversionHolder;
}//end reverse
//sets userinput field to the reversed string
document.getElementById('inputValueId').value = reverse(conversionHolder);
```

Comment: Your function is spelled `reserve` whereas your function call is expecting it to be `reverse`.

Comment: You do not need to declare `conversionHolder` as parameter, neither pass it when calling the function

Comment: ok i made those changes, and in addition i added an alert("testing") inside of the reverse function. when i click the button it doesn't ever give me an alert. So i assume its not tied?

Comment: function reverse(){
    //picks up value
    var userInput= document.getelementById("inputValueId").value;
    //converts value
    document.getElementById('inputValueId').value= userInput.split('').reverse().join('');
    //passes value outside of function?
    alert("it worked");
}//end reverse

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
function reserve(){
    //picks up value
    var userInput= document.getElementById("inputValueId").value;
    //convert and sets value
     document.getElementById('inputValueId').value = userInput.split('').reverse().join(''); 
}//end reverse
```

Mantain your html as it is. Change only the js part to the above.

Comment: fantastic i was confused on how to handle it within the function, thank you!

Comment: If some answer was useful, please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the parameter, it will give you and undefined value and you don't need it.

```
document.getElementById('inputValueId').value = reserve();
```

or if you correct the mistyp

```
document.getElementById('inputValueId').value = reverse();
```

that should be enough.